# Unwanted Keyerror with loc in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to loop through a subset of my dataframe to find all the Nan values and print the column name and row location to a dictionary.

the output should look something like this:

```
{'row': 2, 'column': First Name*, 'message': 'This is a required field'}
```

Here is the code I have so far to achieve this:

```
errors=[]
req_cols = ['First Name*','Last Name*','Country*','Company*','Email Address*']
bad_nan = df.loc[df[req_cols].isna().any(1)]

for col in bad_nan.columns:
    bad_nan[col] = bad_nan[col].astype('str')
    for i in range(bad_nan.shape[0]):
        if bad_nan.loc[i, col] == 'nan':    
            errors.append({ "row": i,
                            "column": col,
                            "message": "This is a required field" })
```

I have tried to replace == 'nan' with =='np.nan' and I still get a keyerror. It is showing me that the keyerror is found in the section of code below

```
if bad_nan.loc[i, col] == 'nan':
```

I am really stuck on why I am getting a keyerror: 0 here any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `'nan'` is your nan values in string format in your dataframe

Comment: I tried to convert them to str form to see if that would solve my issue, my first thought was the keyerror was being raised because it was not recognizing the data. In my dataframe they are just blank which they are shown as NaN but in the actually CSV file there is no data in the cells.

Comment: okay would it be possible to share your csv file on cloud storage along with your code? You can share minimal reproducible example

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BPxRQ6rERk4u3soFezkqicodCM1yFUOg?usp=sharing @Himanshuman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were getting error because there was no row with index value 0 in the `dataframe bad_nan`. What we can do is instead loop through the index values itself. Also use `np.NaN` for filtering blank values.

```
import numpy as np

for col in bad_nan.columns:
    bad_nan[col] = bad_nan[col].astype('str')
    for i in bad_nan.index:
        if bad_nan.loc[i, col] == np.NaN:
            errors.append({ "row": i,
                            "column": col,
                            "message": "This is a required field" })
```